# Enter Unicode Symbol?

Tags: unicode, emoji

How can I enter Unicode emoji into programs on Ubuntu using only the keyboard?

I'm trying `[ctrl] + [shift], 1F1E6` in terminal but the find window ends up poping up when I get to `F`.

Comment: @wjandrea the top answer on that question is what I'm trying in my question.

Comment: You need to press Ctrl+Shift+ **U**, and **then** type `1F1E6`.

Comment: @wjandrea it works but after I do that I have to press Ctrl+shift+U again before it appears

Comment: You just have to press some unrelated key or key-combination, so Space or Enter work more easily. When you press Ctrl+Shift+U again, you're starting another Unicode sequence.

Comment: Note that GUI apps show an underlined "u" plus the sequence, as you're typing it, but CLI apps don't.